# Postgresql: build skytools and pg_top on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

guys! Everething's good with linux servers, but there is a big problem with postgres when i'm going to use it on windows servers, because i need londiste and pg_top, but cannot build it from source and there is no prebuild packages.
I'm on postgres 9.0.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can get skytools to run on Windows. Besides, use Hot Standby instead. pg_top would likely need a little love to get working.